# Pycharm debug flask subprocess.call split error?

Tags: flask, werkzeug

related code in werkzeug/_reloader.py  func:restart_with_reloader

here is my args:

```
['C:\\Users\\14792\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2020.3.5\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev\\pydevd.py', '--multiproc', '--qt-support=auto', '--client', '127.0.0.1', '--port', '55255', '--file', 'D:/PycharmProjects/py3_demo/flask_demo/runFlask.py']
```

Once i starting debug in pycharm, error occured by this line:
`exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)`

and error log is:
`can't open file 'C:\\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

It seems that the path of `'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2020.3.5\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev\\pydevd.py'` is split by blank space in error

And i know set use_reloader=False may works, but I wonder to know why the problem above happened

I re install Pycharm, and changed debug path to D:\PyCharm-2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py, it works ok

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to escape the space as well.